# Why $n^{\underline k} \le n^k$?

Tags: factorial

As in the title,

I cannot prove why $n^{\underline k} \le n^k$

$n^{\underline k}$ is denoted as falling factorial. That is $n^{\underline k} = n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times (n-k+1)$

Can anyone help me out this, please?

Comment: If all else fails, try induction.  You know that $n\frac{1}{~}=n\leq n = n^1$ yes?  You should see that $n\frac{2}{~}=n\times (n-1)\leq n\times n=n^2$ because the final term in the product of the left is less than the final term of the product on the right (*that is to say, $n-1\leq n$*).  Continue with this.

Comment: That seems obvious: each factor is $\le n$ and there are $k$ factors!

Comment: Perhaps your post should specify that $1\le k \le n$?

Comment: Note, we really should specify that $n$ here must be a natural number.  If you otherwise were to set $n$ as something like... $\frac{1}{2}$ let's say... then this is false.

Comment: @hardmath $k$ doesn't need to be bounded above by $n$, but for the notation to make sense it does need to be a natural number.  In the event that $k$ exceeded $n$ (*and $n$ is natural*) then you would have just had the falling factorial become zero.

Comment: Very good. Thank you so much all the helps! And, yes, it bounds $1 \le k \le n$, and they are natural number set. Thanks! It is simple as it is!

Comment: Show that $n^{\underline{k}}$ is the number of injective functions from a set of size $k$ to a set of size $n,$ there are injective and non injective functions, so $n^{\underline{k}}\leq n^k.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $k$ terms in the product $n \times (n-1) \times \dots \times (n - k +1)$. Each one of them is positive and inferior to $n$. So the product is inferior to $n^k$.

One way of seeing there are $k$ terms is remarking that $n - (n-k+1) + 1 = k$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $n$ objects and we are to pick $k$ objects to assign to a list of length $k$,

- if we pick with replacement, there are $n^k$ different lists of length $k$;
- if we pick without replacement, there are $n^{\underline k}$ different lists of length $k$.

And ways to pick with replacement include every way to pick without replacement, so

$$n^{\underline k} \le n^k$$